# What are some resources for writing professional philosophical research articles?

Tags: reference-request, metaphilosophy, methodology

I am a philosophy graduate student. I have written several papers, but I've never been able to publish them, and they all got rejected. Therefore, I started to think that my skills were not good enough. What is the best resource for writing philosophical research articles to improve my research skills?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine something more specific than reading papers and books and support from your teacher.

Comment: As @MauroALLEGRANZA says: this is the sort of thing you should talk your advisor about. We neither have your writing samples nor your reasons for rejection so it is difficult to see what there is to improve in the first place

Comment: @emesupap I know that is the most obvious way to use my supervisor/advisor's help. But I cannot rely on them because "they are busy with something else at the moment." I asked them several times, but every time, they responded this way.

Comment: @user466441 that sounds like a problem. of course an advisor should be busy, but they should make at least some time for you. If you can barely get their help, you should consider having a conversation with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Chicago Manual of Style" is widely used in the humanities, including philosophy.

"The MLA Handbook" or "The APA Publication Manual" are also commonly used in academic writing.

**More specifically on the subject, check these out:**

"Writing Philosophy: A Guide for Canadian Students" by Lewis Vaughn and Lewis R. Gordon.

"Writing Philosophy Papers" by Zachary Brewster and Michael Brewster.

"A Beginner's Guide to Writing in Philosophy" by Thomas E. Wartenberg.